# Downloding dependencies from password protected Nexus repository using a local proxy

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, proxy, repository, nexus

I'm using IntelliJ and I'm working with JAR libraries sitting behind a password protected Nexus repository. I frequently need to inspect sources, but IntelliJ fails to find them because (it seems) it doesn't support password protected repos (at least, it failed when I attempted to add it using Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories, not asking for a password).

If there any workaround?

After some research I learned that I could run a local Nexus instance on my machine set it up in a way that proxies the corporate Nexus... but that seems overkill. Is there any a simple proxy I can install? Alternatively: if I code a simple http server that will just forward requests adding the http auth headers, would that work?

Some clarifications:

- The projects I'm working with are using Scala/SBT. I've tried adding the Ivy plugin to Idea, with no success.
- The password protected repository is set up in m2/settings.xml (password encrypted using settings-security.xml). Maven can use it without problems. I've instructed IntelliJ to use the same settings.xml configuration, but that didn't work. It seems that the code that tries to automatically download sources tries only the Nexus repositories in Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `.m2/settings.xml` file with repository config. IntelliJ respects these settings.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html and specifically https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Even though the repository is in my settings.xml, IntelliJ is not using it. I've added clarifications in the question.

Comment: I assume that there is a configuration issue. I use Maven settings.xml here and IntelliJ is picking it up. You could also check out: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-projects-tool-window.html (search for 'settings.xml').

Comment: Do you have a password protected Nexus repo in your settings.xml? If yes: are your passwords in plain in the settings.xml, or are you using password encryption via settings-security.xml?

Comment: I have a password protected Artifactory repo. Passwords are plain in settings.xml (server-xml-element with sub-elements id, username, password).

Comment: What if I want to use password stored in the environment variables in the settings.xml file? Maven plugin doesn't replaces those variables.